# How can I make the query faster during counting 325,899 rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, indexing

**The VISITS table**

```
CREATE TABLE `VISITS` (
 `USER_ID` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `VISITED_IN` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`,`VISITED_IN`),
 CONSTRAINT `VISITS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `USERS` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**The index I have**

| KEYNAME | TYPE | UNIQUE | PACKED | COLUMN | CARDINALITY | COLLECTION | NULL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER_ID | BTREE | NO | NO | USER_ID VISITED_IN | 1 2244 | A A | NO NO |

**What am I trying to do?**

There are 325,899 rows inside the VISITS table and all of these are for a single user. `(USER_ID = "C9YAoq")`

I counted the number of rows that were added in the last `60 minutes`, `24 hours`, `7 days`, `30 days`, `6 months`, and `12 months` in the same query.

Currently, The query takes between 12 to 15 seconds to count the all rows

**The query**

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_60_MINUTES,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_24_HOURS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_7_DAYS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_30_DAYS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_6_MONTHS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_12_MONTHS
FROM VISITS WHERE USER_ID = 'C9YAoq'
```

**How do I handle the rows where the date is more than 12 months?**

Simply, I scheduled cron jobs in PHP and that is run every day.

The user is very very rare to reaching to 325,899 visits in 1 year but I'm trying to handle bad scenarios if happened.

How can I make the query faster during counting 325,899 rows?

Also, How can I make the delete faster for expired rows?

Can I improve the index more than that?

---

**Update: According to the comments, I enabled explain and here is the result**

| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE | PARTITIONS | TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS | KEY | KEY_LEN | REF | ROWS | FILTERED | EXTRA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | VISITS | NULL | REF | USER_ID | USER_ID | 765 | CONST | 1 | 100.00 | USING INDEX |

Comment: What is the execution plan ?

Comment: You can add `WHERE <= 12 months` to save some time.

Comment: @jarlh Probably won't help unless there are lots of users whose lat visit is more than 1 year ago.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Could you explain more to me what you mean?

Comment: Run `explain` before your query. This will not affect anything , I just want to see the execution plan. The index look correct to me

Comment: @ErgestBasha Check now.

Comment: @Barmar Check now.

Comment: @luq891 it seems good to me. Filtered is 100.00, the index is used. You should check again for larger data

Comment: The index is only used for the `WHERE` clause. Since all the rows have the same user_id, the index doesn't actually do anything. All the counting still has to be done sequentially, that doesn't use the index.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I'm looking to add an extra column in the VISITS table to make the index faster, But still don't know what column must be.

Comment: @Barmar The table is not for only one user, It's for all the users. I'm testing the performance only. Is there any way to make the query faster? Thanks

Comment: I Know it's not for one user, that's just the reason why the index says "Filtered: 100.0" now.

Comment: @luq891 the only suggestion I can give is adding an date condition. For example if you are searching data for one year change `WHERE USER_ID = 'C9YAoq'` to `WHERE USER_ID = 'C9YAoq' and VISITED_IN >='2021-06-03'`

Comment: @ErgestBasha That's the same suggestion jarlh made. It won't help unless that filters out lots of users.

Comment: @Barmar If I added 10 different users inside the table, Does that will change the result?

Comment: @luq891 no, it will have impact if you have data for the user 'C9YAoq' older than 12 months, which you don't want in the result

Comment: Probably not. The index is being used to narrow down to the user. But it still has to scan all those users to count the date ranges. That's the slow part.

Comment: This problem I'm trying to solve two weeks ago and I am still without any result. Is there any alternative scenario to count the visits?

Comment: This shouldn't work but try creating an index on just the time field and use that (via `USING INDEX`) to see if that helps. Or try editing the index to be on a substring of USER_ID (you might be hitting a limit on index length or something)

Comment: I think I'll keep the current scenario without any change and as I said it is very rare to reach 325,899 visits for a single user in 1 year. It is only the effects of perfectionism, Gonna killed me :(

Comment: @Barmar I'll keep the current scenario, Is the index still useful or should I delete it?

Comment: The index may still be useful for other queries, like `WHERE username = 'xxx' and visited_in > 'yyyy-mm-dd'`

Comment: Specifically, the answer below suggests running 6 separate queries, each with a different date range. The index should make them more efficient.

Comment: How does this Question differ from the others like i that I have discussed at length????

Comment: If you have one row per day per user in the Summary table, that will be at most 366 rows (per 12 months) to read from the summary table.  That is likely to be "fast enough".

Answer (score 2):

First you need to execute an EXPLAIN statement for having execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_60_MINUTES,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_24_HOURS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_7_DAYS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_30_DAYS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_6_MONTHS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_12_MONTHS
FROM VISITS WHERE USER_ID = 'C9YAoq'
```

Once you get the execution plan you will have information where the problem come from.

if execution plan is ok perharps you server have a mismatched configuration. So if you want to investigate this i recommand using MySQL profiler to see where the problem come from.

You can also use another approach for solving your problem.

Write a store procedure that execute one query for each of you metrics, so you will have 6 queries in the store procedure and you can return the 6 metrics you need. As queries are more simple and have execution plan more efficient, i think you will get faster.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, The best solution is to keep the current scenario.

Comment: The execution plan is in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a this kind of process. May be this is not the answer for you, but using these kind of summery table will gives you better performance.

> **Note: `Test` mean my DB name. change it accordingly.**
>
> **Note: better to use "COALESCE(fieldname,0)" for DB fields to ignore any issues from null values.**

1. Create a table like follows

> ```
> CREATE TABLE userwise_visit_history (
>   user_id INT (10),
>   last7days INT (11),
>   last24h INT (11),
>   last6month INT (11),
>   last12month INT (11),
>   created_date TIMESTAMP 
> );
> ```

2. Daily run this job through a scheduler at 12.00 AM

/*
Everyday at 12 AM run this query
*/

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_visited_history ()
BEGIN

-- TRUNCATE TABLE `Test`.`userwise_visit_history`;
/* truncate table removed with active user modification */
DELETE FROM userwise_visit_history WHERE user_id IN  (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM visits 
WHERE CAST(visited_in AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE));

INSERT INTO `Test`.`userwise_visit_history` (`user_id`, `last7days`, `last24h`, `last6month`, `last12month`)
SELECT user_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN visited_in >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_7_DAYS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN visited_in >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_30_DAYS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN visited_in >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_6_MONTHS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN visited_in >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_12_MONTHS
FROM visits 
WHERE visited_in < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)
/* this section will help to optimize the function process by using only for the active users */
AND user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM visits 
WHERE CAST(visited_in AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE))
/*end of active user modification */
GROUP BY user_id ;

 
END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

added below part to the previous function to more optimize the solution.

> AND user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM visits  WHERE
> CAST(visited_in AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE),
> INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND  TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE))

That query part will identify the previous day active users only. They are the only users who need to update the history table and others historical data is keep as it is.

3. When ever you need to execute your query for a user, run this function

   /* To Get the login data use following function*/

> ```
> DELIMITER $$
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_visited_Data(IN usr_id INT)
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE i_last60min INT;
> DECLARE i_last24h INT;
> DECLARE i_last7days INT;
> DECLARE i_last30Days INT;
> DECLARE i_last6month INT;
> DECLARE i_last12month INT;
>
> SELECT    `last7days`, `last24h`, `last6month`, `last12month` INTO i_last7days, i_last30Days, i_last6month, i_last12month
>   FROM 
>   `Test`.`userwise_visit_history` 
>   WHERE user_id = usr_id;
>   
> SELECT
> COUNT(CASE WHEN visited_in >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_60_MINUTES,
> COUNT(CASE WHEN visited_in >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_24_HOURS
> INTO i_last60min, i_last24h
> FROM visits WHERE user_id = usr_id
> AND visited_in >= TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE);
>
> SELECT i_last60min LAST_60_MINUTES, i_last24h LAST_24_HOURS, i_last7days + i_last24h LAST_7_DAYS, 
> i_last30Days + i_last24h LAST_30_DAYS,  i_last6month + i_last24h LAST_6_MONTHS, 
> i_last12month + i_last24h LAST_12_MONTHS;
>
>  
> END$$
>
> DELIMITER ;
> ```

4. Run the procedure with the user name

   CALL my_proc_visited_Data(1);

[image]

Comment: I am not shure that this , which is very complicated, will help with performance ... You just take the query and put it into a store procedure.

This does not improve the execution plan.

Comment: @Alaindeseine its not just a query. We inserted every thing into a summery table. First procedure your ran only for 1 time at 12:00 AM (daily with "WHERE visited_in < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)"). After that your referring that summery table for 7days, 6monts, 12 month and 1 year. So you do not want to access the visit data again and again which is the most time consuming part. Your accessing visit data only for the current date (today) information ("WHERE visited_in >= TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)"). This is same kind of data warehousing.

Comment: Creating user_id, visited_in fields related indexes/ compound] are really really impotent.

Comment: @luq891 I added some modification to the first procedure to optimize it more.  Everybody facing these kind of issues while working with this much of data sets. Sometime optimizing the execution plan wont help us. At the moments summery tables are very useful. These all queries i tested and give it to you. So, you just give a try. Nothing to loose. Sometime you may have to change the table and field names. :). "Not forcing you. Juts try to help you :)"